# Automatically generate type from Array

Tags: typescript

I have a hypothetical api that returns color values based on user selection.

Take an array with string values:

```
const Input1 = ['red', 'blue', 'purple'];
const Input2 = ['blue', 'white'];
```

And the api returns objects:

```
const Response1 = {
  red: "#ff0000",
  blue: "#0000ff",
  purple: "#aa22ff"
}

const Response2 = {
  blue: "#0000ff",
  white: "#ffffff"
}
```

I can manually create the types:

```
type TResponse1 = {
  red: string;
  blue: string;
  purple: string;
}

type TResponse2 = {
  blue: string;
  white: string;
}
```

But is it possible to derive the type? Something along the lines of this:

```
type TGenerated1 = {[any-value-from-Input1: string]: string};
type TGenerated2 = {[any-value-from-Input2: string]: string};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your arrays into unions and then use those unions as keys in your types:

```
const Input1 = ['red', 'blue', 'purple'] as const;
const Input2 = ['blue', 'white'] as const;

const Response1: TGenerated1 = {
    red: "#ff0000",
    blue: "#0000ff",
    purple: "#aa22ff"
}

const Response2: TGenerated2 = {
   blue: "#0000ff",
   white: "#ffffff"
}

type TGenerated1 = { [K in typeof Input1[number]]: string }
type TGenerated2 = { [K in typeof Input2[number]]: string};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAkmADgVygRhgXhgbQOQBOApgCZ4A0MeARgDbJEVUoGK2MC6MAhhDKJCgBuAFADo8JKgBMWXDXqNKeAO4ALAJZROPPuOEix4CQCUiERMaJoAXDAAqAcSJgiBbtpIZsAbxEwYYhI7ACIAYgAzCIAGWOiQ8n8YOgZQsLjoqISkljYiNO5uaWkskQBfQ30YMwsraTsnFzcPUllfJJT8mHCMrMSA9S0u8KjRiJDywygAT0QiB2dXd09vGB9cAGkYDTAYGbmQCMkUdBwwZABbajcODjtoAh2AcxgK-fnGpZaSNrXN7d270OxxkZ0u1wIt3uUEeYCeZSEQA)

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach to the asnwer posted before me.
But I would take the step using the type from the `Response1`/`Response2` objects inside the record itself like so:

```js
const Input1 = ['red', 'blue', 'purple'] as const;
type Input1Tuple = typeof Input1

const Input2 = ['blue', 'white'] as const;
type Input2Tuple = typeof Input2


const Response1 = {
  red: "#ff0000",
  blue: "#0000ff",
  purple: "#aa22ff"
}

const Response2 = {
  blue: "#0000ff",
  white: "#ffffff"
}

type TGenerated1 = Record<Input1Tuple[number], typeof Response1[Input1Tuple[number]]>
type TGenerated2 = Record<Input2Tuple[number], typeof Response2[Input2Tuple[number]]>
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesnt work however because I dont know the response yet, its variable and returned by the api. Sorry for the confusion.